# Why is Drupal not pulling data from Salesforce?

Tags: crm

I am using the [Salesforce Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/salesforce) module and have created field mappings. However, when I run cron, no data is pulled into the site.

I have set the `Direction` to `SF to Drupal` for all field mappings.

I have enabled the following triggers:

- `Salesforce object create`
- `Salesforce object update`
- `Salesforce object delete`

Comment: do you see any watchdog logs? notices or errors in Drupal?

Comment: I only received an error when I tried to enable `Salesforce SOAP` and forgot to include the library. Other than that, nothing.

Comment: are you trying to send data from a custom table?